# How to setup ffmpeg for the same record method which is used in OBS studio "replay buffer" feature (recording of last X seconds continuously)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, obs-studio

I do like how OBS studio "replay buffer" feature works (recording of last X seconds continuously).

But it seems like over-sophisticated heavy application to be used for this only purpose.

As I understood, it uses ffmpeg for recording. And ffmpeg seem to support scripting (or configuring, I'm not sure which term fits better here).

So I tried to find some instructions on how to make it with ffmpeg scripting only (without OBS studio), but hadn't found clear and straightforward one yet.

So how to make ffmpeg to do this:

1. begin video recording which will be finished only after some particular action (e.g. hotkey is pushed)
2. each second delete part of recording which is older than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the recording to segments and use a playlist file to combine them later. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373148

**Step 1**:

```
ffmpeg -i input force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*4) -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_wrap 6 -segment_list list.m3u8 -segment_list_size 6 seg%d.ts
```

This will save the recording in segments of 4 seconds. Once 6 segments have been written, the next segment will overwrite the first file. The playlist is updated accordingly.

**Step 2**:

```
ffmpeg -i list.m3u8 -c copy video.mp4
```

or

```
ffplay list.m3u8
```

The duration of the preserved footage is `20 < duration < 24`.

If you want a complete solution that does this for you I have made a script for it https://github.com/MAPReiff/ShadowRePlay-Linux

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.